# Word 2019 Appendix numbering advances letter instead of number

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I am working on adding several Appendices to my Word 2019 document.  When I demote parts of the Appendix, however, the A advances instead of the number 1:

**Appendix A Sample Json Messages 

A.1 Sample 1 

B.1 Sample 2 

C.1 Sample 3**

I want it to look like this:

**Appendix A Sample Json Messages 

A.1 Sample 1 

A.2 Sample 2 

A.3 Sample 3**

What should I change to make it work this way?

Comment: "When I add another section to the Appendix" - try adding a page break not a section break.

Comment: Sorry, not using a section break.  I'm just adding text and demoting it to the second level.